# Angular.js: complex expression in limitTo filter inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

```
<li ng-repeat="chapter in book.chapters | limitTo:$parent.book.limit" >...</li>
```

this doesn't work but if i debug the scope of the `li`, `$parent.book.limit` has got a valid value (i've set it in the controller of course).

Isn't that code piece legit? Is there a way to achieve it?

The variable limit is on the parent because needs to be dynamically changed from other actions.

Plunk related: http://plnkr.co/edit/Hlz0nV

Comment: Looks OK, not sure why you need to use $parent, though. Send a plunk with more code.

Comment: Looks fine for me, too. Couldn't reproduce the error. http://plnkr.co/edit/2UFCKZvZ7bJ0cy0c7aCi?p=preview

Comment: added a modified plunk, mirroring my situation. @bekite yes your plunker works but you have two distinct controllers, i have only one and my children are in an array of the parent scope

Comment: sorry maybe it't now what you want. But removing $parent from $parent.book.limit works. Is there a reason you want to call $parent?

Comment: thank you! no there wasn't a reason, only i thought that was the right way.. instead it was much simpler! Would you mind to answer to the question with that suggestion so i can check your answer as the right one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove $parent from $parent.book.limit and it should work.